# Acumatica source control git

Tags: git, acumatica

I am using the Bonobo GIT Server to run a private repository.  I have successfully set up Studio for the c# source.  I am trying to determine the best way to include the customization project along with it.  I read several articles and cases on here, but I can't seem to get it right.

I created a folder and included it in my Studio project, but GIT will not upload the supporting dll files because of the .gitignore file that studio creates.

I tried creating a separate folder and using a git gui to upload it. This worked but then I could not export the project again after changes. I got an error related to the .git folder and the export failed.

What is the recommended method to get the Customization Project loaded into git and then track changes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

With **GIT** we use the **Source Control->Save Project To Folder** feature of the Customization Project Editor:
[image]

The **Source Control->Set Up Source Control** feature can be used with **Microsoft Team Foundation Server**.

Customization projects are Zip archive. Essentially what the **Source Control->Save Project To Folder** does is extract the archive content to a folder. You can then add that folder to your **GIT** source folder. The archive content closely matches the project Items which you can see in **File->Edit Project Items**.

This article discuss the procedure in details:
[Customization and Source Control](https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/customization-and-source-control.html)